# Magento 1.9 front-end custom page create

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, 404-page

I need to create front-end custom page  `URL` like this `www.demo.com/declaration/success`

I have tried but page is showing `404` error. My codes are the following

`D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\sliver-exchange\app\code\local\SilverExchange\Declaration\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SilverExchange_Declaration>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </SilverExchange_Declaration>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <declaration>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>SilverExchange_Declaration</module>
                    <frontName>declaration</frontName>
                </args>
            </declaration>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <declaration>
                    <file>declaration.xml</file>
                </declaration>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <declaration>
                <class>SilverExchange_Declaration_Helper</class>
            </declaration>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <declaration>
                <class>SilverExchange_Declaration_Block</class>
            </declaration>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\sliver-exchange\app\code\local\SilverExchange\Declaration\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
<?php  

class SilverExchange_Declaration_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function IndexAction()
    {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Declaration"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("demo", array(
                "label" => $this->__("declaration"),
                "title" => $this->__("declaration")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function successAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();
    }
}
```

`D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\sliver-exchange\app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\layout\declaration.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<declaration_index_index>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="declaration/declaration" name="declaration_index" template="declaration/index.phtml" />
  </reference>
</declaration_index_index>


<declaration_index_success>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="declaration/declaration" name="declaration_success" template="declaration/success.phtml" />
  </reference>
</declaration_index_success>


</layout>
```

`D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\sliver-exchange\app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\template\declaration\success.php`

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="std">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Declaration Success</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update your controller to : `app\code\local\SilverExchange\Declaration\controllers\SuccessController.php`

   ```
   <?php  
   class SilverExchange_Declaration_SuccessController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function IndexAction()
       {
        ...
       }
   ```
2. Update the layout handle to : `app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\layout\declaration.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
   <declaration_success_index>
       ...
   </declaration_success_index>
   ```
3. Dont **forget** the `app/etc/modules/SilverExchange_Declaration.xml`

   ```
   <config>
       <modules>
           <SilverExchange_Declaration>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </SilverExchange_Declaration>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```

Now you can call your url like this: **www.domaine.com/declaration/success**

Comment: You're welcome.