# Magento 1.9 how to create custom frontend page programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I am beginner in Magento. I want to create a page and show all products in it with this URL: `example.com/products`.

I've read many tutorials and [answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195641/magento-1-9-front-end-custom-page-create), Is there any tutorial that could help me to create a custom page programmatically from scratch?